# Validation accuracy fluctuating while training accuracy increase?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I have a multiclassification problem that depends on historical data. I am trying LSTM using loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'. The train accuracy and loss increase and decrease respectively. But, my test accuracy starts to fluctuate wildly.

What I am doing wrong?

**Input data:**

```
X = np.reshape(X, (X.shape[0], X.shape[1], 1))
X.shape
(200146, 13, 1)
```

**My model**

```
# fix random seed for reproducibility
seed = 7
np.random.seed(seed)

# define 10-fold cross validation test harness
kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=False, random_state=seed)
cvscores = []
for train, test in kfold.split(X, y):
    regressor = Sequential()

    # Units = the number of LSTM that we want to have in this first layer -> we want very high dimentionality, we need high number
    # return_sequences =  True because we are adding another layer after this
    # input shape = the last two dimensions and the indicator
    regressor.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(X[train].shape[1], 1)))
    regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

    # Extra LSTM layer
    regressor.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True))
    regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))
    # 3rd
    regressor.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True))
    regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

    #4th
    regressor.add(LSTM(units=50))
    regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

    # output layer
    regressor.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)))

    # Compile the RNN
    regressor.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

    # Set callback functions to early stop training and save the best model so far
    callbacks = [EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=9),
             ModelCheckpoint(filepath='best_model.h5', monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True)]


    history = regressor.fit(X[train], y[train], epochs=250, callbacks=callbacks, 
                        validation_data=(X[test], y[test]))

    # plot train and validation loss
    pyplot.plot(history.history['loss'])
    pyplot.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
    pyplot.title('model train vs validation loss')
    pyplot.ylabel('loss')
    pyplot.xlabel('epoch')
    pyplot.legend(['train', 'validation'], loc='upper right')
    pyplot.show()


    # evaluate the model
    scores = regressor.evaluate(X[test], y[test], verbose=0)
    print("%s: %.2f%%" % (regressor.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
    cvscores.append(scores[1] * 100)
print("%.2f%% (+/- %.2f%%)" % (np.mean(cvscores), np.std(cvscores)))
```

**Results:**

[trainingmodel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgbvl.png)

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEQSG.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing here is overfitting. This means your model keeps learning about your training data and doesn't generalize, or other said it is learning the exact features of your training set. This is the main problem you can deal with in deep learning. There is no solution per se. You have to try out different architectures, different hyperparameters and so on.

You can try with a small model that underfits (that is the train acc and validation are at low percentage) and keep increasing your model until it overfits. Then you can play around with the optimizer and other hyperparameters.

By smaller model I mean one with fewer hidden units or fewer layers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Will you try to follow a different approach for this multiclassification problem that the variable to predict depends on past events?

Answer (score 1):

you seem to have too many LSTM layers stacked over and over again which eventually leads to overfitting. Probably should decrease the num of layers.

Answer (score 0):

Your model seems to be overfitting, since the training error keeps on reducing while validation error fails to. Overall, it fails to generalize.

You should try reducing the model complexity by removing some of the LSTM layers. Also, try varying the batch sizes, it will reduce the number of fluctuations in the loss.
You can also consider varying the learning rate.